# Getting InvalidIndexError: (slice(115770, None, None), slice(None, None, None))

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, tensorflow, keras

Trying to predict closing stock price of a corporation (Apple Inc.) using the past 50 day stock price.

**Getting: pandas.errors.InvalidIndexError: (slice(115770, None, None), slice(None, None, None))**

```
#Import the librarires
import math
import pandas_datareader as web
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, LSTM
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use('fivethirtyeight')

#Get the stock quote
df =web.DataReader ('AAPL', data_source='yahoo', start='2017-01-01', end='2022-05-31')

.....

#Create the data sets x_test and y_test
x_test = []
y_test = dataset[training_data_len:, :]
for i in range(50, len(test_data)):
    x_test.append(test_data[i-50:i, 0])

#Convert Data to a numpy array
x_test = np.array(x_test)

#Reshape the data
x_test = np.reshape(x_test, (x_test.shape[0], x_test.shape[1], 1 ))

#Get the models predicte price values
predictions = model.predict(x_test)

#inverse transform the prediction 
# basically unscaling the values and have the prediction contain the same values as the y_testdataset, given the x_dataset
predictions = scaler.inverse_transform(predictions)
```

Answer (score 0):

`dataset[training_data_len:, :]` locates the multiindex column, you may want `loc` which locates rows and columns

```py
dataset.loc[training_data_len:, :]
```